# Why was Evey's head still shaved?

Tags: plot-explanation, v-for-vendetta

In [*V for Vendetta*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_for_Vendetta_(film)), Evey has her head shaven while in captivity:

[image]

After she is released, it appears that a significant amount of time goes by and Evey is shown living a somewhat normal life.

Evey comes back to see V on November 5th, as she promised. Her hair appears to be the same length as when she left captivity:

[image]

**Did Evey continue to keep her head shaven?  Was there just that short of time that elapsed from her release from captivity until she meets V again?**

Comment: I've no official proof, but in my opinion, the longer hair represented the "old" Evey.  The shaved head look is for the "new" Evey created by V so she decided to keep it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are lines from movie when Evey comes to meet V again. She has retained her shaved head look.

> **V**: I must confess, every time I heard a siren, I worried about you.
>
> **Evey**: I worried about myself for a while. But then, one day, I was at a market... and a friend, someone I had worked with at the BTN, got
>   in line behind me. I was so nervous that when the cashier asked me for
>   my money, I dropped it. My friend picked it up... and handed it to me.
>   She looked at me right in the eyes...didn't recognize me. Whatever you
>   did to me worked better than I'd have imagined.

Script here [V for Vendetta Script](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=v-for-vendetta)

Evey with long hair was person scared of many things. After what V did to her, she's now become stronger. Since her new shaved look also helps in not being recognized ... she feels this is her new self. She associates her new look to her new self. She does not want to go back to being old scared Evey.

Answer (score 1):

She tells V that after she left the Shadow Gallery she bumped into an old colleague who did not recognise her. Although this is mainly played down as to how much her personality has changed following her experience 'in custody', these events did coincide with her first sporting the new hair do and this must have played some role in her not getting recognised. It is implied by the domino montage that some months appear to pass during which she may have actively continued to keep her hair short for this purpose. Better than a fake ID?

This is just my own opinion but it is something I must have asked myself in the past as after reading the question I felt somewhat arrogant for feeling like I already knew the answer ;-)